# search on user type column in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have entity `User` which contains property `Status` of type `DictionaryItem` and this is mapped as a `UserType`. Now i want to make the following linq statement:

```
Session.Query<User>().Where(x => x.LoginStatus.Code == "").ToList();
```

I got following exception:

> Additional information: could not resolve property: Code of: User

I know the problem is that I search using my custom type(property Code existed on my `DictionaryItem` user type). nhibernate session query generates SQL statement when i call `ToList()`, but `LoginStatus` is not Reference type, only `User` type, is any workaround to make query on user type?

Edit 1:
Below source code:

```
    public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DictionaryItem LoginStatus { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.LoginStatus).CustomType<DictionaryItemCustomType>();
    }
}
public class DictionaryItem
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    }
 public class DictionaryItemCustomType : IUserType
    {
        public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return ((DictionaryItem)x).Id == ((DictionaryItem)y).Id;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(object x)
        {
            return x.GetHashCode();
        }

        public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
        {
            object value = NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(rs, names);
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return AutofacServiceHostFactory.Container.Resolve<IDictionaryRepository>().DictionaryItems.First(x => x.Id == (int)value);
        }

        public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
        {
            DictionaryItem dictionaryItem = value as DictionaryItem;
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, dictionaryItem == null ? (object)null : dictionaryItem.Id, index);
        }

        public object DeepCopy(object value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
        {
            return DeepCopy(original);
        }

        public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object Disassemble(object value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public SqlType[] SqlTypes
        {
            get { return new[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32.SqlType }; }
        }

        public Type ReturnedType
        {
            get { return typeof(DictionaryItem); }
        }

        public bool IsMutable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

Bd look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,   
    [LoginStatusId] [int] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DictionaryItem](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: Can you please post the entities' properties and their relations or the tables structure?

Comment: I have added source code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DictionaryItem statusAlias = null;
User userAlias = null;
return Session.QueryOver<User>(() => userAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => userAlias.LoginStatus, () => statusAlias)
    .Where(() => statusAlias.Code == "")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Rather than LoginStatus statusAlias = null; should by DictionaryItem statusAlias = null; Your query looks very amazing for me, can you explain? I've got following exception "not an association: LoginStatus"

Comment: @Adam, Check your mapping between the two entities defined in the `.hbm` file, and for the query you have to alias the `DictionayItem` entity in order to resolve their property and use them, see the association section in this pag: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx.

Comment: First, thank you for the link. Your query works perfectly when i have that kind of mapping for LoginStatus property: References(x => x.LoginStatus); but when i have Map(x => x.LoginStatus).CustomType<DictionaryItemCustomType>(); there is an exception with assosaction:  "not an association: LoginStatus". I think that can be correct behaviour of nhiberante because LoginStatus  is mapped as a Int value, there is no information about relation with dictionary item table. If you think otherwise than me I can create sample project and send you because is very curious case for me.

Comment: Query which works perfectly with my code looks like: Session.Query<User>().Where(x => x.LoginStatus == IDictionaryRepository.GetByCode("here code")).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is incorrect.  DictionaryItem should not be mapped as a custom type.  It looks like another entity to me.

```
Map(x => x.LoginStatus).CustomType<DictionaryItemCustomType>();
```

The above indicates that you only want to map a single column.  You are wanting to map the actual entity DictionaryItem to User.  You need to do something like this:

```
References(x => x.LoginStatus, "LoginStatusId");
```

Then you need to map the DictionaryItem:

```
public class DictionaryItemMap : ClassMap<DictionaryItem>
{
    public DictionaryItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);  //You'll need to do something else here for identity columns
        Map(x => x.Code);
        Map(x => x.Description);
    }
}
```

After you have this mapping in place you can do the query mentioned above by MGA.

```
LoginStatus statusAlias = null;
User userAlias = null;
return Session.QueryOver<User>(() => userAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => userAlias.LoginStatus, () => statusAlias)
    .Where(() => statusAlias.Code == "")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I Know what i want. I don't want to use Reference mapping for DictionaryItem type property because each time when i call that property, shoot will come to dadabase and therefore i wany mapping in my custom type from repostiory, I know also that i can remove my custom type, and add Reference mapping and using 2nd level cache for not shooting dictionary item data, but i want use my custom type;)